# String Literal Type Conversion In JSX and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm having a problem converting a string to a string literal.

The string literal is defined as follows:

```
type myLiteral = "cats" | "dogs"
```

Then I have a component that I want to pass a type from an 'inputted' string.

```
const myString:string = "cats"
const notQuiteSure:any = myString as myLiteral

React.createComponent(<myComponent inputtedType={notQuiteSure}/>
```

I'm getting squigglies all over the place. I have tried using the `as` keyword and the `is` keyword to do a 'cast' but nothing seems to work.

Anybody have any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
const myString: myLiteral = "cats";
```